# Why is versioning required to enable MFA delete on S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I mean you can have MFA delete capabilities without versioning. So why this constraint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MFA Delete is primarily intended to prevent *accidental* data loss due to deletion or overwrites.

MFA Delete requires a versioned bucket, because if a bucket isn't versioned, you can permanently "delete" any object (that is, you can obliterate its contents) simply by overwriting the object, which is done by creating a new object with the same key -- so requiring MFA for deletions in that case would accomplish no real purpose since it would be trivial to override or work around, whether accidentally or on purpose.

With MFA Delete active (and versioning active, as required), you can still "overwrite" an object by creating a new object with the same key, but that isn't really an overwrite. No data is lost, because the prior current version of the object simply becomes a previous version of the object.  Its contents are retained in the bucket, and the "overwrite" change can be reverted by deleting the newly-created version (with MFA, of course), which automatically promotes the most recent previous version of the object back to being the current version of the object.

But versioning can be suspended on a bucket, which would bring us back to the same problem, and that's why MFA Delete also requires MFA to be used if you try to suspend versioning on the bucket.

Depending on what you are trying to accomplish, requiring MFA on all API calls might be more appropriate than MFA Delete:

> **Note**
>
> MFA Delete and MFA-protected API access are features intended to provide protection for different scenarios. You configure MFA Delete on a bucket to ensure that data in your bucket cannot be accidentally deleted. MFA-protected API access is used to enforce another authentication factor (MFA code) when accessing sensitive Amazon S3 resources. You can require any operations against these Amazon S3 resources be done with temporary credentials created using MFA.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Versioning.html#MultiFactorAuthenticationDelete

Answer (score 0):

This might give you the answer - 
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/securing-access-to-aws-using-mfa-part-3/

Answer (score 0):

You can use versioning to keep multiple versions of an object in one bucket.

Basically, using MFA-protected S3 buckets will enable an extra layer of protection to ensure that the S3 objects cannot be accidentally or intentionally deleted by the AWS users that have access to the buckets.

Comment: I get that. But you can have MFA delete without versioning. So why is it a **necessity** ?

Comment: To prevent accidental deletes